# Keyboard layout ignored after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard-layout

My keyboard layout worked fine in 19.10, and stopped working after upgrading to 20.04.

I'm getting some generic qwerty layout now, even though my own layout is listed in the language settings panel as the only layout.

The listed layout is "se+dvorak_a5" and displays correctly when clicking the eye button next to it.

So... what now?

Comment: One thing you may want to try is to add another layout, e.g. _English (US)_, besides the one you want to use. If you do, an input source menu should show up in the top bar. Use that menu to explicitly switch to English and then back to your preferred layout. If you are lucky, that will make a difference.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the tip. I tried this, and expected a menu, but none has shown up so far since yesterday.

Comment: Considering the huge pain they've made it to even install a layout (that you helped me with earlier) and the fact that they couldn't even bother to preserve my wallpaper during the upgrade to 20.04, I can't say I have much hope.

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me. Please note that your edits to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` were overwritten during the upgrade, so you need to redo that.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks! Sorry for not replying, I was positive that I already had. I decided to switch to Windows until Ubuntu designs a proper layout system and stops pulling this crap where they overwrite my data after having offered no alternative solution.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Do you want to create an answer, or should I?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem as well, but for portugue brazil layout that just got completely wrong layout after a system update yesterday. My solution is quite simple, just overwrite the "br" file in the path "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/" with an ubuntu 18.04 "br" file. You can give a look below and see the differences I've found between them.

Hope it can help

```
22c22
20.04 <     key <AD03> { [            e,              E,        degree,          degree ] };
---
18.04 >     key <AD03> { [            e,              E,      EuroSign,        EuroSign ] };

44c44
20.04 < 000};
---
18.04 > };

161c161
20.04 <     key <AC10> { [            s,               S,               ssharp,            U1E9E ] };
---
18.04 >     key <AC10> { [            s,               S,               ssharp,           ssharp ] };

237c237
20.04 <     key <AC08> { [            s,               S,               ssharp,            U1E9E ] };
---
18.04 > "does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Ubuntu has started shipping with my layout built-in, but it can only be found if you know the secret knock. You basically have to enable "show additional layouts" in Gnome Tweaks, or something along those lines (I don't do it *that* often).

Nevertheless, after an update the layout can still turn out to have disappeared. The weird but easy fix in this situation is to find this secret switch again, realize that your preference has been reverted for unknown reasons, and enable additional layouts again. After that the layout is restored.

The weird part about this is that the layout obviously always exists on the system, but for some reason can't be referenced unless it's visible in system settngs.